# Configure Asterisk for lan with SRTP enabled SipDroid

Tags: encryption, cryptography, android, voip

I want to have a secured call over internet between two android phones. I have found [SipDroid](https://github.com/prajwol/sipdroid-fork) which is an open source SIP client for Android. And also I have followed [this](http://blogs.digium.com/2012/11/14/how-to-install-asterisk-11-on-ubuntu-12-4-lts/) to install Asterisk, Dahdi and LibPre on my Ubuntu 10.04.

I want to have it configured it for Local Lan first, although it is intended to work in the 3G Network .

---

### What I want to know is:

1. Am I moving in the right direction.
2. Some link which might explain me the components I need to achieve what I want.
3. I want to know which server (APACHE/MySQL) I might install to have the asterisk up on my localhost so that the two calling phones can give its IP Address as a server and some link educating about its installation procedure.

Thanks in advance for your consideration.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? What is it you are trying to protect yourself against? Are you planning on offering a service?

Comment: I want to have a secured call over internet between two android phones.
I am trying to encrypt my calls and also the user ip addresses which might be exposed in SIP without TLS. And its really not clear who might try to intercept the channel to sneak on the call.
And yes I am trying to build a service for some specific client.